# .pdf opening 403 Forbidden issue in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, php-7, file-permissions, xampp, http-status-403

I have an issue in opening .pdf file

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me it has something to due with file permissions.

Please execute the following command on your site root.

```
sudo chmod -R  +775  .
```

Comment: Thank you @Joao71 but it's still not working.